# Can one eat on Sunday

Tags: food, havdalah

Can one eat on Sunday if he hasn't heard Havdalah yet? If not, what happens if he already ate: should he say Havdalah?

Answer (score 3):

Per Rabbi Doniel Neustadt if he will have wine before Chatzos on Sunday he should preferably wait and not eat unless he is weak.

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5761/bereishis.html

Per Orach Chaim 299:5 you can make Havdala even if you ate already. The Mishna Berura says this applies even if the eating was done intentionally.

Havdala can be said till Tuesday if not said for some reason prior to that. (Rambam Hilchos Shabbos Perek 29 Halacha 4)

Answer (score 3):

The *Aruch Hashulchan* [299:16](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.A6.D7.98_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.98.D7.96) quotes a dispute between all of the "heavy hitters" over the correct version of the *g'mara* in *P'sachim* 107. He quotes the opinion that when one recites *havdala* late (after dawn of Sunday morning), he only says *borei p'ri hagafen* and *hamavdil ben kodesh l'chol* (i.e. the non-whited-out parts [here](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/havdalah.html)). And he only recites these *b'rachos* **if he has not yet eaten**. This appears to be the opinion of the *Baha"g*.

He quotes most others, including the *Ram"a*, who hold that one may still recite *havdala* until (and including) Tuesday even if one has eaten.

And to answer your first question, since on Sunday the person is practically still waiting to recite *havdala*, which is a *mitzva*, it should be treated like any other limited-time *mitzva* in that other activities (most prominent among which is eating) should not intervene.

Comment: What is your source for the last paragraph? He refers to 296:14 where he seems to say that you can eat, but if you think on Saturday night that you'll get a cup on Sunday then you should refrain from eating until the next day

Comment: @ba My source would have been the _Aroch Hashulchan_, and what you're saying sounds right. It might have even been what I had in mind but didn't express clearly. I will revisit and try to clarify, but feel free if you would like to before I get to it.