# Why is it allowed to delay Havdalah until Tuesday afternoon?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, havdalah

I have never understood how Havdalah can be said until Tuesday at sunset. I mean, if one cannot eat or drink (except water) until saying Havdalah, is it possible that one can go **three** days without eating?

Why does such an allowance even exist?

Comment: Going three days on water is medically quite plausible.

Comment: What if you forgot, ate lots of food, and remembered on Tuesday?

Comment: Do you regularly expect that all allowances in Halakha apply to common cases? Why?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3864/can-one-eat-on-sunday

Answer (score 1):

The allowance to say *havdala* until Tuesday is primarily for those who forgot to say it on *motzei shabbat*.

The language of [SA OC 299:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.299.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) is quite clear

> שכח ולא הבדיל במוצאי שבת מבדיל עד סוף יום ג' 
>  One who **forgets** and
>   didn't say Havdala on motzei Shabbat says Havdala until the end of
>   Tuesday

Outside of voluntary fasts<sup>1</sup>, there is no allowance to delay voluntarily for convenience.

As such, one who forgot would likely have eaten as normal.

<sup>1. Thanks to @DoubleAA for reminding us of this. I quote: "If one is fasting starting on Sunday less than 72 hours one can delay on purpose and just say the candle blessing on sat night. (If fasting more than 72 hours you'd say Havdala on Shabbat afternoon after Plag.)"</sup>

Comment: Thank you both very much. Please forgive me, but I need clarification. It is not clear to me. If one forgot to say it Motzei Shabbat and, obviously, ate and drank Motzei Shabbat, Sunday, etc, does he go ahead with full Havdalah when he remembers (even on Monday or Tuesdday)? Thank you again.

Comment: @Sidney76 no from Sunday at daybreak on, use only the wine, not the candle or spices, and don’t say the first paragraph (hinei El yeshu’ati…). Source: [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/havdala/) The rationale is the spices are there to console for the departing additional soul that was there on Shabbat (and left by Sunday), and the candle is there as a reminder Adam created fire on motzei shabbat (and thus this doesn't apply from Sunday on)

Comment: mbloch, thank you again so very much. I greatly appreciate the knowledge--and time--you provided me. Shavua tov.

Comment: I'm still not convinced you can't delay on purpose for extreme Tosefet Kodesh, though indeed you might only be allowed to drink water. We allow people for the same reason to say Kiddush well before dark.

Comment: Not just _voluntary_ fasts. We do the same thing when observance of _tisha b'av_ is on Sunday.

Comment: @Daniel That's different. Even many of the opinions that say Havdala can only be said until Sunday at sundown agree there because it must be Chazal enacted Havdala in that case delayed. Similarly some opinions hold that one who must eat on Tisha Bav on Sunday doesn't say Havdala yet because it was enacted only to be said Sunday night in that case.