# Water fasting from Sunday until Tuesday, to save time, and Havdalah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, fast-days, havdalah, water-fasting

The main mitzvah of Havdala is to say it on Saturday night. [(Source.)](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/the-law-if-one-did-not-say-havdalah-on-motzei-shabbos/#_ftn3:%7E:text=The%20main%20Mitzvah%20of%20Havdalah%20is%20for%20it%20to%20be%20recited%20at%20night%20%5Bon%20Motzei%20Shabbos%5D.%5B3%5D)

In a particular week, you have a lot of schoolwork you want to get done.  You decide to do a water fast for a few days, to [save time](https://blog.thefastingmethod.com/top-5-benefits-of-intermittent-fasting-2/#:%7E:text=Fasting%20saves%20time,or%2016%20days.).  You'll consume only water, not food.

A.)  Are you allowed to do a water fast from Saturday night until Tuesday morning, and then recite [partial Havdalah](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/01/01-08/#halacha7:%7E:text=one%20who%20did%20not%20make%20havdala%20Saturday%20night%2C%20even%20if%20he%20has%20eaten%2C%20should%20make%20havdala%20over%20wine%20with%20the%20berakha%20by%20the%20end%20of%20Tuesday%20(SA%20and%20Rema%20299%3A6%3B%20MB%2019).%20This%20applies%20to%20the%20berakhot%20of%20Ha%2Dgafen%20and%20Ha%2Dmavdil%2C%20but%20the%20berakhot%20over%20fragrances%20and%20fire%20are%20made%20only%20on%20Saturday%20night.) on Tuesday morning?

B.)  Is this fine to do, despite the fact that Havdalah will be delayed?  Or do the authorities advise against doing so?

#### Related questions

- [Water fasting from Sunday until **Friday,** to save time, and Havdalah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136635/fasting-from-sunday-until-friday-to-save-time-and-havdalah)
- [Why is it allowed to delay Havdalah until Tuesday afternoon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98252/saying-havdalah-until-tuesday-sunset)

Comment: Why not just start your fast 10 minutes later after havdala? This case feels ridiculous

Comment: @DoubleAA:  It may sound ridiculous, but it's based on an actual case which happened to me.  ❧  Assume that you didn't eat any meal on Shabbos afternoon.  Drinking wine or grape juice on an empty stomach, and not consuming any food with it, may cause an unhealthy blood sugar spike.  It's perhaps not the wisest idea.

Comment: You are required to eat a bread meal every shabbat afternoon

Comment: Are you talking about a case where there is no one else around to make Havdalah or at least drink the wine  instead you?