# Water fasting from Sunday until Friday, to save time, and Havdalah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, fast-days, havdalah, water-fasting

In a particular week, you have a lot of schoolwork you want to get done.  You decide to do a water fast for most of the week, to [save time](https://blog.thefastingmethod.com/top-5-benefits-of-intermittent-fasting-2/#:%7E:text=Fasting%20saves%20time,or%2016%20days.).  You'll consume only water, not food.

A.)  Are you allowed to do a water fast from Saturday night until Friday morning, even though this means you'll miss out on saying Havdala that week?

B.)  Is this fine to do, even though you'll miss Havdalah?  Or do the authorities advise against doing so?

#### Related questions

- [Water fasting from Sunday until **Tuesday,** to save time, and Havdalah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136632/fasting-from-sunday-until-tuesday-to-save-time-and-havdalah)
- [Why is it allowed to delay Havdalah until Tuesday afternoon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98252/saying-havdalah-until-tuesday-sunset)

Comment: You could make havdala (without a candle) late on Shabbat afternoon, before sunset, so you won’t actually miss out on havdala

Comment: I'm a big proponent of fasting for health and spiritual reasons, but sticking to a 6 day fast will require more of your time than eating would

Comment: @יהושעק: Why would a six-day fast take up any time?  Fasting [saves time](https://blog.thefastingmethod.com/top-5-benefits-of-intermittent-fasting-2/#:%7E:text=Fasting%20saves%20time,or%2016%20days.).

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica there are time and productivity gains on days 1, 2 and 3, but after that you spend more time dealing with your fast and the weakness associated with it than you save by not eating or preparing food. And Friday afternoon is a disaster.

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica my email is on my profile, feel free to reach out

Comment: When fasting for that long even if drinking water you will have less energy and focus so everything you do will take more time to accomplish. Whatever time you think you'll be saving by not eating will cost you in becoming less efficient

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of fasting "to save time".  Can't you eat on the fly, while doing what you need to do?  The Talmud says:

> Rabbi Yitzhaq said: Is what the Torah prohibited you not enough that you need to [also] prohibit yourself things that are permissible?

(Source: [Nedarim Yerushalmi 9:1.](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Nedarim.9.1.5?lang=bi#:%7E:text=Is%20it%20not%20enough%20what%20the%20Torah%20forbade%20you%20that%20you%20want%20to%20forbid%20other%20things%20for%20yourself%3F))

Comment: I once found myself so busy at work that I took the cheese off the sandwich I had brought for lunch and ate it without the bread, so that I wouldn't have to wash and bentch.  I may have done the wrong thing, but the desire to save time was definitely there.